# Umbraco 7.5.1 umbracoNaviHide

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

To be able to filter out items that should not be rendered with .Where("Visible") I need a property called umbracoNaviHide that returns true or false.

In earlier versions this was added to the Generic tab. However now you cant append to that tab anymore.

How would I accomplish hiding pages now?

Here's my foreach:

```
 @foreach (var Area in Model.Content.Children.Where("Visible"))
 {
```

Here's a statement about it. But I cant find any workaround.

> > Related Changes Summary - 7.4 beta - Option toCannot add properties to the "Generic properties" tab
>
> Description - In the 7.4 beta it's not possible anymore to add
>   properties to the "Generic properties" tab. I know this has been done
>   because properties can be a bit hidden on that tab and usually are
>   better on a separate tab. But there are situations where the
>   properties are better on that tab.

Comment: You could just put it in another tab, couldn't you? I usually have a Navigation tab where I control visibility (via umbracoNaviHide), display name in navigation, browser title and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add that property as a true/false datatype to any tab. However, it's important to note that umbracoNaviHide does not do anything special it is just a magic string, that, when implemented as a true/false datatype, it works with

```
.Where("Visible").
```

Personally I don't use it anymore.  If I need to cause items to be visible or not then I would name the property more specifically.  For example, it is often useful when implementing menus where you want some nodes to be visible but not others.  I generally have a Menu tab where one of the properties is a true/false type called *Show in menu* with an alias of `showInMenu`.

In code it could be something like below (I have used TypedContentAtXPath to get the parent node of a specific doc type. Of course there are various ways of doing this)

```
var homeNode = Umbraco.TypedContentAtXPath("//MyHomePageDocType").First();
var menuItems = homeNode.Children.Where(item=>item.GetPropertyValue<bool>("showInMenu"));

foreach(var item in menuItems)
{
    // Do your menu stuff here
}
```

Hope that helps

J

Comment: Thankyou! I went ahead and created a menu tab and a new property for it. However I am getting issues using a foreach on this. foreach (var parentPage in home.Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<Bool>("showInMenu")))

Comment: var home = CurrentPage.Site(); here's my home reference. @wingyip

Comment: you need to return an IPublishedContent for the home node to use the code I wrote

Comment: If you are trying to get your homepage, what is the doctype of the homepage?

Comment: The doctype is "Home". I am trying to get all the first level of childrens under "Home".

Comment: So substitue 'Home' for the 'MyHomePageDocType' above.  Make sure the alias of your doctype is the right case (it could be 'home' not 'Home')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139427/discussion-between-codehiker-and-wingyip).

Comment: It also works with .Where(x => x.IsVisible()). You can rename property and put any description as you want. It's just required to keep the alias as described. It's nothing else than custom property, but you already have helper methods for retrieving value. It can be also placed in any tab. Btw. there is/was a hack to place prop in the Properties tab. Try to create tab and name it "Generic properties" and it will land in the Properties tab :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a composition for node visibility with a checkbox to show or hide the menu item. And you can inherit this to the doc types that you do not want to show.

And then you can do

```
_homeNode.Children.Where(x => !x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("hideInNavigation"));
```

[image: Node visibility]

Hope this helps!